# The application stops running when executing getLac(),getCellId()

Tags: android

This is my code,i cant able to get the value of cellid and Lac value.This is my code,

```
public class lac extends Activity {
    private int mCid ;
    private int mLac ;
    GsmCellLocation location;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TelephonyManager tel=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    location = (GsmCellLocation) tel.getCellLocation();

        mLac=location.getLac();
        mCid=location.getCid();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"LAC="+mLac+"CellId="+mCid+type,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    }
```

When i run the emulator it says that the application stops running unexpectedly.I used the permission `(ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION),(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)`.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from the LogCat output?

Answer (score 0):

```
mLac=location.getLac();
```

I am sure this is returning null (-1) and you are getting `NullPointerException` because your `gsm location area code is unknown`, Try running this on your device instead of emulator.